# Why do these two lines of code not produce the same results?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm pretty new to python and I was trying to set up a TKinter interface with 9 input boxes. I was using the first line of code below to track each widget's value but when I tried to clean my code up by using the second line below I found that all three nested arrays are tied to the same 3 widgets. I feel like I'm missing something obvious here.

```
data = [[StringVar(), StringVar(), StringVar()],
        [StringVar(), StringVar(), StringVar()],
        [StringVar(), StringVar(), StringVar()]]

data = [[StringVar() for i in range(3)]for x in range(3)]
```

Edit:
I'm posting the entirety of my code,

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk, StringVar
import asyncio
import websockets

ip = "10.30.128.92"
port = 5678

root = Tk()
status = StringVar()


async def send_data(*args):
    buffer = [[0]*3]*3
    try:
        for i in range(3):
            for j in range(3):
                val = float(data[i][j].get())
                if 0 < val < 255:
                    buffer[i][j] = val
                elif val >= 255:
                    buffer[i][j] = 255
                else:
                    buffer[i][j] = 0
        print(buffer)
    except ValueError:
        pass
    status.set("Connecting...")
    root.update()
    await asyncio.sleep(1)

    try:
        async with websockets.client.connect("ws://{}:{}".format(ip, port)) as websocket:
            status.set("Connected")
            root.update()
            await asyncio.sleep(1)
            status.set("Transmitting Values")
            root.update()
            await asyncio.sleep(1.3)
            print("Connection at ws://{}:{} established".format(ip, port))
            print("Awaiting Server reply code")
            msg = await websocket.recv()
            print(msg)
            print("Transmitting RGB values")
            await websocket.send(str(buffer))
            status.set("Data Transmitted ✓")
            root.update()
            await asyncio.sleep(1)
            print("Closing connection at ws://{}:{}".format(ip, port))
            websocket.close()
    except ConnectionRefusedError:
        status.set("Unable to Connect")
        root.update()
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        print("Unable to connect to server at w://{}:{}".format(ip, port))


def run(*args):
    asyncio.run(send_data(args))


root.title("LED Manager")
root.iconbitmap('exbICO.ico')

mainframe = ttk.Frame(root, padding=".3i")
mainframe.grid(column=0, row=0)
root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

#Holds the values of each entry box
#data = [[StringVar(), StringVar(), StringVar()],
#        [StringVar(), StringVar(), StringVar()],
#        [StringVar(), StringVar(), StringVar()]]


data =[[StringVar() for i in range(3)] for x in range(3)]

print(data)
#Holds references to the entry box widgets
data_entry = [[0]*3]*3

#Creates ttk Entry widgets that feed into values of data[][] and the places them into the frame
for i in range(3):
    for j in range(3):
        data_entry[i][j] = ttk.Entry(mainframe, width=7, textvariable=data[i][j])
        data_entry[i][j].grid(column=i+1, row=j+2)
        data_entry[i][j].focus()

#Creates the labels on all entry boxes and buttons
ttk.Label(mainframe, textvariable=status).grid(column=4, row=2)
ttk.Label(mainframe, text="Red 0-255").grid(column=0, row=2)
ttk.Label(mainframe, text="Green 0-255").grid(column=0, row=3)
ttk.Label(mainframe, text="Blue 0-255").grid(column=0, row=4)
ttk.Label(mainframe, text="LED #1").grid(column=1, row=1)
ttk.Label(mainframe, text="LED #2").grid(column=2, row=1)
ttk.Label(mainframe, text="LED #3").grid(column=3, row=1)
ttk.Button(mainframe, text="Send", command=run).grid(column=4, row=3)

for child in mainframe.winfo_children(): child.grid_configure(padx=5, pady=5)

root.bind('<Return>', run)
while True:
    try:
        root.update_idletasks()
        root.update()
    except TclError:
        sys.exit(0)
```

Running this with the list comprehension yields different behavior for me than if the other line is uncommented

Comment: <s>Because the outer list comprehension just replicates the references of already created objects; you just create `StringVar()` no more than three times.</s> My bad, sorry.

Comment: @jbndlr: No it doesn't. List multiplication would do that, but list comprehensions don't.

Comment: @jbndlr no, these should both create 9 `StringVar` objects.

Comment: The posted code doesn't show anything that would cause the described problem. I suspect the actual code used list multiplication.

Comment: I see a bug in `data_entry = [[0]*3]*3`, but not in the list comprehension.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They do the same thing:

```
from tkinter import *
win = Tk()
data = [[StringVar(), StringVar(), StringVar()],
        [StringVar(), StringVar(), StringVar()],
        [StringVar(), StringVar(), StringVar()]]
print(data)

data = [[StringVar() for i in range(3)]for x in range(3)]
print(data)
```

Yeilds:

> `[[<tkinter.StringVar object at 0x0000024E4EC16470>, <tkinter.StringVar object at 0x0000024E4EC162B0>, <tkinter.StringVar object at 0x0000024E4EE7E400>],
>   [<tkinter.StringVar object at 0x0000024E4EF8B3C8>, <tkinter.StringVar object at 0x0000024E4EF8B438>, <tkinter.StringVar object at 0x0000024E4EF8B4A8>],
>   [<tkinter.StringVar object at 0x0000024E4EF8B518>, <tkinter.StringVar object at 0x0000024E4EF8B588>, <tkinter.StringVar object at 0x0000024E4EF8B5F8>]]`

and

> `[[<tkinter.StringVar object at 0x0000024E4EF8B6D8>, <tkinter.StringVar object at 0x0000024E4EF8B668>, <tkinter.StringVar object at 0x0000024E4EF8B748>],
>   [<tkinter.StringVar object at 0x0000024E4EF8B780>, <tkinter.StringVar object at 0x0000024E4EF8B7B8>, <tkinter.StringVar object at 0x0000024E4EF8B7F0>],
>   [<tkinter.StringVar object at 0x0000024E4EF8B828>, <tkinter.StringVar object at 0x0000024E4EF8B860>, <tkinter.StringVar object at 0x0000024E4EF8B898>]]`

If you are asking why `0x0000024E4EC16470` != `0x0000024E4EF8B6D8` (the first instance) that's because that number tells you where in memory the object is. The are both `StringVar` objects, but they are just at different places. For instance I imagine your neighbors are also `human` objects, but since they are your neighbors they have a different address!

Comment: I posted the rest of my code if you could take a look and see if maybe something else is causing the behavior it would be much appreciated.

Comment: @AnOrphan I imagine the problem is at `data_entry = [[0]*3]*3` because as pointed out in the comments using the multiplication operator like that ***just replicates the references of already created objects*** so your `data_entry` variable has 9 different ways to *update* the one number it holds (the [0]) and each `[i]` or `[j]`th element you subsequently use all refer to this singular element

Comment: But the code works when I use the manual assignments of the StringVar and it doesn't when I use the list comprehension even when ```data_entry = [[0]*3*3] ``` is being used. If both statements have the same behavior wouldn't this be irrelevant?

Comment: Never mind looks like that was causing the problem. I'm curious tho as to why it worked with the manual method regardless of how ```data_entry``` was created

Comment: Actually the problem was ```buffer = [[0]*3]*3``` not ```data_entry = [[0]*3]*3```

Comment: @HalOwens Interesting. I'm sure it is still the same problem though! I recommend using list comprehensions to make lists in general, so you avoid these issues.